# Check if generator is empty without consuming it

Tags: python, iterator

I filter a location for entities other than the player:

```py
entities = filter(lambda entity: entity != player, location.entities)
```

If there are any entities, print each one of them:

```py
if any(entities):
    print('Entites nearby:')
    for entity in entities:
        print(entity)
```

However, using `any()` consumes the elements in the generator, as the subsequent for loop iterates zero times.

Is there a way to check if a generator is empty or check its length without resorting to lists or having to manually reset the iterator?

Comment: You could [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) it.

Comment: Why don't you just do the loop without checking?

Comment: @KellyBundy because my use case involves printing out a separate message if no entities exist (`"There are no entities nearby"`)